# Registry context menu addition works under win7 but not win10

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-7, windows-10, registry

I have a registry edit that works under windows 7 but not under windows 10 and I can't figure out why.

My goal is to add a context menu action, "Run R script", to appear in the context menu when someone right-clicks on a file ending in ".R". Here, the command is to launch a .cmd (.bat) script with the file name as an argument.

Under windows 7, this is relatively straightforward. Adding a key under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\R_auto_file\shell\Run Rscript\command` works fine. For example, from `cmd.exe` the command might be something like this:

`reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\R_auto_file\shell\Run Rscript\command" /v "" /t REG_SZ /d "\"C:\path\to\run_rscript.cmd\" \"%1\""`

After running the above, right clicking on an R file shows this:
[image: context menu option]

while that option does not show up for non-R files.

So far so good. The problem is that this doesn't work under windows 10. What's curious is that if I replace `R_auto_file` with `*` in the `reg add` command, then "Run R script" does show up in the context menu, and it does work. But the context menu action shows up for all files, not just R files. That is undesirable because I want this option to only show up for R files, and ultimately I want different context actions for different files.

#### Edit (more info) ------

Here is what's under .r in the `FileExtx` key. (exported as a .reg file and copy and pasted here)
```

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.r]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.r\OpenWithList]
"a"="rstudio.exe"
"MRUList"="acb"
"b"="a"
"c"="{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\\OpenWith.exe"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.r\OpenWithProgids]
"R_auto_file"=hex(0):

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.r\UserChoice]
"Hash"="SkJTR1uegvY="
"ProgId"="Applications\\rstudio.exe"
```

```

Comment: "R_auto_file" is an automatically created ProgId. This is generally a sign that something is wrong with an installation. I would expect the installation of R to define a custom ProgId with an "open" action. Check in "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts" for the current user choice for .R files, if defined. Otherwise check for the .R association in the HKCR view (read only; don't set values here).

Comment: The R installer does not register .R files in the registry by default (hence why I'm doing it myself). [These](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Does-R-use-the-Registry_003f) are the only registry additions the R installer optionally does

Comment: That doesn't change that you need to check the registry keys that I mentioned to get the current association or user choice for .R files. It's almost certainly not "R_auto_file" on the Windows 10 system, since adding a menu command there has no effect on .R files.

Comment: Updated the post with the requested info. I don't really know what that registry key means, or how I would need to modify it to add a context menu.

Comment: The FileExts key is used by the Windows shell to store user choices for opening files, such as from open with => choose another app => look for another app => always use this app. In this case, someone selected to open .R files via rstudio.exe. Windows automatically created a ProgId for this case, and since it's directly for an executable it was created in "HKCU\Software\Classes\Applications\rstudio.exe". You can maybe switch back to "R_auto_file" via the "open with" menu, without having to manually modify the registry.

Comment: Thank you! Based on your comment I just deleted the "FileExts\.r" key (and all it's subkeys"), and now "Run Rscript" appears correctly. Thank you again!

Comment: Feel free to post as an answer and I'll accept. As far as I understand the HKCU "R_auto_file" was being masked by a user choice which is recorded in "FileExts", and that removing FileExts or modifying it somehow would fix the issue.